# Изменение формата ссылки при оправке VK или ICQ

Tags: вконтакте, frontend, icq

Здравствуйте.
По какому принципу изменяется формат ссылки когда в VK оправляешь ее другому контакту?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При чём тут формат? Может имеется в виду другой вопрос, например: "как формируется предпросмотр ссылки?"

Comment: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1959&